# How to access vue store from a component when using with router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to access a variable in the Vuex store from a component.However, when I access the value from the store, it always shows up as empty. I'm using routers to navigate between components

router.js

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home",
        component: HomeView,
    },
    {
        path: "/productview",
        name: "productview",
        component: ProductView,
    },
    {
        path: "/shoppingcartview",
        name: "shoppingcartview",
        component: ShoppingCartView,
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(
        process.env.BASE_URL
    ),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

main.js

```
const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            cart: [],
        };
    },
    mutations: {
        addItem(state, item) {
            state.cart.push(item);
        },
    },
});
createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(vuetify)
    .use(store)
    .mount("#app");
```

ProductView.vue where I modify the cart variable in the store

```
<!-- @format -->

<template>
    
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
export default {
    methods: {
        
        addItemToCart(item) {
            this.$store.commit(
                "addItem",
                item
            );
            
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

ShoppingCartView.vue where I try to access the variable

```
<!-- @format -->

<template>
    <v-container>
        
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        console.log(this.$store.state.cart);
        return { items: [] };
    },
};
</script>
```

The above console.log prints an empty array. Any idea what I am doing wrong ? Thank you

Comment: Means that the array is empty at the time when data() is evaluated, i.e. on component instantiation

Comment: You can use computed property to get data from store.
{
   computed: {
     items(): {
      return this.$store.state.cart;
    }
   }
}

Comment: @DinhTX I have tried that too.. but it still shows as empty

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite understand what you mean, but it has nothing to do with the router. Please take a look at documentation of Vuex with options API, and Vuex with composition API.

Just created example how to use Vuex  with composition api, because I personally prefer it. Here it is:

**main.js**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      cart: []
    };
  },
  mutations: {
    addItem(state, item) {
      state.cart.push(item);
    }
  }
});

createApp(App).use(store).mount("#app");
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <TestVuex />
</template>

<script setup>
import TestVuex from "./components/TestVuex.vue";
</script>
```

**TestVuex.vue**

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="input" />
  <div class="btn"><button @click="add">Add</button></div>
  <div>from the store:{{ cart }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";

const store = useStore();
const input = ref("");

const cart = computed(() => {
  return store.state.cart;
});

const add = () => {
  store.commit("addItem", input.value);
  input.value = "";
};
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case I have ProductView.vue (http://localhost:8080/productview) where I add some value to the store. Then I go to ShoppingCartView.vue (http://localhost:8080/shoppingcartview) and try to access the value from store but I dont get the modified value.

Comment: @sammaniariyarathne Do you reload the page when accessing localhost:8080/shoppingcartview ?
If yes, then you need to use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist to save the value of store before reloading